# How do I cast these void pointers?

Tags: c

Im doing exam review and one of the questions says there is something wrong with this code and im supposed to fix it. I know it has something to do with the void pointer but cant figure it out. Does anyone know what i would do?

```
void whatAmI(void *vp, int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        printf(“Integer: %d\n”, vp);
    } else if (n == 2) {
        printf(“Double: %.2fl\n”, vp);
    } else {
        printf(“Unknown type!”);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try compiling it? What happened?

Comment: no, this is just sample code I was given. I have to cast or something like that but I dont know how.

Comment: Well, `vp` is a pointer and is neither an integer nor a float. And those aren't real quotes.

Comment: it is really a bad example of code as integer and float cannot be represented with the same raw data!

Comment: @daouzli; What? Are you serious ?

Comment: Okay if you considere n as determining the type of data, that could make sense but it's finally not a good approach!

Comment: @daouzli; A good approach could be using `union` but there you also need a "tag field"/ "discriminant".

Comment: @haccks that's indeed a kind of situation where an union can make sense. But it can be considered as overkill!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to  dereference the pointer `vp` to print the value stored at the location pointed by `vp`. But a `void` pointer can't be dereferenced (doing so invokes *undefined behavior*), so you need to cast it:

```
void whatAmI(void *vp, int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        printf("Integer: %d\n", *(int *)vp);  
    } else if (n == 2) {
        printf("Double: %.2fl\n", *(double *)vp);  
    } else {
        printf("Unknown type!");
}
```

Comment: What about strict aliasing rules? Won't dereferencing `(int*)vp` and `(float*)vp` break them here?

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar; *Aliasing refers to the situation where the same memory location can be accessed using different names.* But here memory is referenced using same name `vp` :)

Comment: @haccks : Thanks. I always get nervous when I see `*(int*)something` in the code.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar; Haven't you tried `qsort` and its `compare` function ? You should try that and then you will know more abot generic pointer `void *`. By the way you can read more about [Strict aliasing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/99010/2455888) here.

Comment: The `"Double: %.2fl\n"` suggests the pointer points to a `double` object and in that case you have to use `*(double *) vp`.

Comment: @ouah; Yes. I missed that. Its late night here. Too tired now.